# Screen flickering random colors in Andengine android. How to fix?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am making a demo in Andengine for android and when i run my game on my Galaxy SIII, the screen is messed up. There is a ball and it is supposed to bounce a couple times but when i run it it displays like randoms colors and the ball is split in half and all around the screen.Here is my code:

```
package com.example.andeng2;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;

public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    Scene scene;
    protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
    ITextureRegion playerTextureRegion;
    PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
                ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                        CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
        return options;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadGfx();
        // resources have been loaded
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

    }

    private void loadGfx() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        // width and height have to be power of 2^x
        playerTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 64, 64);
        playerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(playerTexture, this, "player.png", 0, 0);
        playerTexture.load();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0f, 125f, 58f));
        physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
        createWalls();
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

    }

    private void createWalls() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FixtureDef WALL_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT-15, CAMERA_WIDTH, 15, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        ground.setColor(new Color(15,50,0));
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, WALL_FIX);
        this.scene.attachChild(ground);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, playerTextureRegion, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sPlayer.setRotation(45.0f);
        final FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Body body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, sPlayer, BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYER_FIX);
        this.scene.attachChild(sPlayer);
        physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sPlayer, body, true, false));
            pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in S3 device but i didnot found any flickering.I think you are  using player.png bigger image  which is difficult to load into Texture.So check it once. If so,  change your bitmapTextureatlas inputs as per image size